# Adding SRT subtitle to multiple MP4

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, subtitle, srt

I want to add a SRT to a MP4 with matching names from same folder. I want to script it to keep doing this to all files in folder.

This works if I do **1 at a time**, but i have over 1,000 to do. How can I create a batch to do this

ffmpeg -i *source*.mp4 -i *source*.srt -c copy -c:s mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng *destination*.mp4

Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x694 [SAR 1:1 DAR 640:347], q=2-31, 1385 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : VideoHandler
vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : SoundHandler
vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874)
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavc60.40.100 mov_text
[out#0/mp4 @ 000001b40337b680] video:1027151KiB audio:142295KiB subtitle:31KiB other streams:0KiB global headers:0KiB muxing overhead: 0.297458%
size= 1172956KiB time=01:35:42.13 bitrate=1673.4kbits/s speed= 763x